# Jquery script working sporatically under Visual Studio 2010 in MVC3 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a "simple" user maintenance page for a school project.  The jquery script for this page does not work.

My project is using Visual Studio 2010 and the MVC3 framework.  Both are updated to the latest version.  The project is using the Razor view engine.  I am doing my testing locally only.

On one page, I am using Adam Shaw's Full Calendar successfully.  To me, that proves that it is not a Visual Studio issue.

I have tested the code using jsFiddle.net and both the HTML and script worked successfully.

I have examined the page using Firebug and it shows the jquery script file is being successfully loaded.

My html from the view looks like this:

```
<link href="../../Content/UserMaintainance.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/UserMaintainance.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@model TourSystem2.Models.UserMaintainanceViewModel
<h2>User Maintainance</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Delete</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
        <td>Login Name</td>
        <td>Full Name</td>
        <td>Rights</td>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>Comments</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td colspan = "7" class = "br"></td></tr>
    <tr id="1">
        <td><button type="button"  class = "deleteButton"></button></td>
        <td><button type="button"  class = "editButton"></button></td>
        <td>John Stone</td>
        <td>jstone</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>12345</td>
        <td>just some user</td>    
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using the following jquery links in _Layout.chtml:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My testing script looks like:

```
$('.deleteButton').click(function () {
    alert("Deleting user");
});

$('.editButton').click( function () {
    alert("Editing user");
});

$(':button').click(function () {
    alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});

$(":button").css("border", "13px solid red");
```

My CSS file looks like:

```
.deleteButton, .editButton
{
    width : 20px;
    height : 20px;
}
```

Does anyone have any advice on where I should continue looking to fix this issue?

Comment: I forgot to say that I am using Firefox 4.0.1

Comment: You say that it 'does not work'.  What should it be doing, and what is it doing now?

Comment: try to wrap your jQuery calls into document.ready `$(function() { //code });` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Thomas:  The jquery is not functioning at all in the user maintenance page at all.

Comment: @Daniel: I will give that a try shortly.  Knowing my luck, it is that simple and I've been beating my head on the desk for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be that you're trying to attach events to DOM objects that don't exist yet.  You can either try wrapping your jQuery code with `$(document).ready(function() { //your code here });` or move your `script` tag to the bottom of your view page.  Personally I would do both.

Comment: This fixed the issue.  Figures a 1.5 line of code would solve hours of trying to figure it out.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I would also go with Dean North's suggestion of using `Url.Content` to get paths to your scripts. Much safer that way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your scripts are using relative paths.

In MVC3 and razor you should declare your scripts like this...

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/UserMaintainance.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/UserMaintainance.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I did not try this yet... the script links above were generated by dragging/dropping the script from solution manager to the view.  Thank you for the hint.  I'm still trying to get my head in a web programming mode.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you jQuery in

```
$(function () {
  //...
});
```

so it executes when the DOM is ready.  Also are you sure you references to you script files are correct? I would use root relative paths ('/') and not page relative paths ('../') like

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```